# How to destroy specified session

Tags: php, session

Assume that I have this session

```
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY_For_Admin']
```

How to destroy that specific session, and not all sessions that `session_destroy()` does?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you meant "variable" - exactly the same way you would "destroy" any other variable:

```
unset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY_For_Admin']);
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Answer (score 0):

$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY_For_Admin']= '';

or

$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY_For_Admin']= NULL;

or

unset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY_For_Admin']);